# MPMoviePlayerController showing black empty screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a local file in my Application Document folder which have I have downloaded for a server URL:

```
itemMoviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
 [self.view addSubview:itemMoviePlayerController.view];
 itemMoviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
 itemMoviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
 itemMoviePlayerController.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
 [itemMoviePlayerController play];
```

When I play `.mov` file just after I downloaded it, It shows up a black empty screen & app UI is unusable.
But if play same local file next time, it plays fine.
I even verified `playState` & `localState` for `MPMoviePlayerController` they seems fine.
What could be reason for black empty screen?

Comment: Dec 2013 .. TIP - it is hugely flakey about **file name extensions** (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard. Bizarre. Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes. Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken. Finally you can not have more than one onscreen at the same time - they all just go black and fail.

Comment: This looks exactly like my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems fixed after updating device iOS to 5.0.
Seems to iOS SDK issue for previous version

Answer (score 31):

You need to retain your instance of MPMoviePlayerController i.e. as a property or an instance variable. The reference to the movie player is lost if you do not retain it.

Comment: This was the solution for me. It doesn't matter if your project is ARC or not, you still need to retain the instance of MPMoviePlayerController, otherwise it is released and the movie does not work.

Comment: Thanks this solved a bug I've been hunting for a long time as well in exactly the same context; showing a movie in a UITableViewCell.

Comment: This is just.... perfect......!!! Wasted a couple hours till I found this! Nice answer!!!

Comment: I have used MPMoviePlayerViewController and presented it but I am getting black screen while video loading

Comment: I can't believe the answer is this simple.

Answer (score 15):

You could try to put `[itemMoviePlayerController prepareToPlay];` 
before the `[itemMoviePlayerController play];`

The way preferred by Apple to display an only full screen video is to present a modal `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (as Hollance said).
To present it, you should use something like :

```
 moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
 [itemMoviePlayerController play];
```

This is [documented by Apple here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can read there that you should keep a reference to your `MPMoviePlayerViewController`  in order to dismiss it later with

`[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController]`.

Answer (score 13):

I fixed this by putting

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

in my .h file, and calling `self.moviePlayer` in all my code and it worked!

Comment: Not sure why this worked but so others know, it did.

Comment: It is the `strong` property that makes it work for some reason

Comment: That's retaining the movieplayer. If you're just using it's view in another viewcontroller, then that's the only hint that the player needs to be kept around as well.

Comment: #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

Answer (score 7):

You need to use MPMoviePlayerViewController instead. Notice the word "View" in there.

Comment: I even tried using MPMoviePlayerViewController but that too causes same black empty screen

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all. Why should the view-controller variant of the movie player be any different when it comes to pre buffering and identification of the content.

Comment: It shouldn't. However, a common mistake is to use MPMoviePlayerController (without the "View"), which as of iOS 4 just gives you a blank screen (because its view isn't added anywhere). Because of this a lot of old examples no longer work. It did not turn out to be this person's problem, but "black empty screen" is often the result of this API change.

Comment: Helped me. Seems like MPMoviePlayerViewController handles more errors and invokes MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification when anything bad happens. This way you can dismiss movie player when something bad happens more easily.

Answer (score 3):

*I hope this will help. I solved this problem in my project*

```
 -(void)startPlayingMovie
{
    NSLog(@"startPlayingMovie");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"Start_video" ofType:@"mov"]];
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];

NSLog(@"endPlayingMovie");

}
```

Comment: `moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width);` => `moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;`

Comment: it's not, because height and width are reversed

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me. It turns out, I had tried to play the movie while the `UIImagePicker` wasn't dismissed yet.

In my `UIImagePickerDelegate` I had to first dismiss the `UIImagePicker` Popup and then open the `ViewController` managing the `MPMediaPlayerController`:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)infoDict
{
    //the first thing to do: dismiss the media picker
    if ([ipPop isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [ipPop dismissPopoverAnimated:ANIMATION_SETTING];
    }

    myMediaPlayerViewController * playerVC = [[myMediaPlayerViewController alloc] initWithMediaDict:infoDict];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:playerVC animated:ANIMATION_SETTING];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and it made me crazy.  It would *work* on one view controller fine (audio and video), but not work on another (black screen with just audio).  In the end, all I did was CHANGE THE ORDER of the calls: I simply waited until I was done configuring the movie player before adding it to the view.  In other words, I called "addSubview" on the line just before the call to "play".

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I'm using to play a file from URL:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:contentUrl]];
movieViewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewController];
[movieViewController release];
```

It seems to work fine for me. Two notes:

- Some simulators (like the current iOS 5.0) crash when playing a movie, but it works on a real device
- If you leave out the `movieSourceType` part, a black screen is shown for about a second before the movie starts

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved it changing the extension of the file being played from .mpg to .mp4. apparently MPMoviePlayerController expects a correct extension, though from the documentation  it is not clear to me that this is a requirement:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Supported Formats This class plays any movie or audio file supported
>   in iOS. This includes both streamed content and fixed-length files.
>   For movie files, this typically means files with the extensions .mov,
>   .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of the following compression
>   standards:

Answer (score 0):

you must do like that with CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) in the finished callback!

```
-(void)playMovieAtURL:(NSURL*)theURL

{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(2, 246, 317, 70);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];

    // Register for the playback finished notification. 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:theMovie];

    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately. 
    [theMovie play];
} 

// When the movie is done,release the controller. 
-(void)myMovieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[aNotification object]; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                  object:theMovie];

    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Release the movie instance created in playMovieAtURL
    [theMovie release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. After playback there comes an empty screen, which prevents me to play video again. 
Well here is my work around. That way play button doesn't disappear.

```
[self.movieController stop]; 
[self.movieController prepareToPlay];
[self.movieController pause];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, If you are using http URLs, make sure you disable App Transport Security in your projects ***.plist** file. It will also cause a black screen.

**Add the following code:**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

**Here:**

```
   [INSERT CODE ABOVE HERE]
  </dict>
</plist>
----- BOTTOM OF PLIST FILE
```